# return found path in glob

Tags: python, glob

If I have a `glob('path/to/my/**/*.json', recursive = True)`, function returns something like:

```
path/to/my/subfolder1/subfolder2/file1.json
path/to/my/subfolder1/subfolder2/file2.json
path/to/my/subfolder1/subfolder2/file3.json
path/to/my/subfolder1/file4.json
path/to/my/file5.json
...
```

I'd like to get only part that starts after `**` in the glob, so

```
subfolder1/subfolder2/file1.json
subfolder1/subfolder2/file2.json
subfolder1/subfolder2/file3.json
subfolder1/file4.json
file5.json
...
```

What is the best way to do it? Does glob support it natively? Glob input is provided as commmand line hence direct str-replace may be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.commonprefix` on the returned paths, then `os.path.relpath` using the common prefix to get paths relative to it.

An example from a Node.js project with a whole bunch of `package.json`s.

```
>>> pkgs = glob.glob("node_modules/**/package.json", recursive=True)[:10]
['node_modules/queue-microtask/package.json', 'node_modules/callsites/package.json', 'node_modules/sourcemap-codec/package.json', 'node_modules/reusify/package.json', 'node_modules/is-bigint/package.json', 'node_modules/which-boxed-primitive/package.json', 'node_modules/jsesc/package.json', 'node_modules/@types/scheduler/package.json', 'node_modules/@types/react-dom/package.json', 'node_modules/@types/prop-types/package.json']
>>> pfx = os.path.commonprefix(pkgs)
'node_modules/'
>>> [os.path.relpath(pkg, pfx) for pkg in pkgs]
['queue-microtask/package.json', 'callsites/package.json', 'sourcemap-codec/package.json', 'reusify/package.json', 'is-bigint/package.json', 'which-boxed-primitive/package.json', 'jsesc/package.json', '@types/scheduler/package.json', '@types/react-dom/package.json', '@types/prop-types/package.json']
>>>
```